# Check if a control is "touching" another control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to check if a Windows Forms control is "touching" another Windows Forms control within the same Form.

Example: 
There are two buttons inside a Form. Lets say that the two buttons are moveable within the boundaries of the Form. How would one check if the two button are touching (or any System.Control for that matter)?

How can this be checked?

Comment: Do you need to check each control against all of the others?

Comment: I need to check against every control that might be "touching" the control I am checking. In other words, I need do a test whether there is a control "touching" another control anywhere around it (left, right, above, bellow, diagonally).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the control `Bounds` against other controls and check if they have any intersct.

```
// if your first control is specified you can use the following code
foreach (Control c2 in Controls)
{
    if (!c2.Equals(c1) && c2 is Button /* if you want it to be just buttons */
    && c1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c2.Bounds))
    {
        // c1 has touched c2
    }

}
```

If all controls can move and you want to see when they touch each other you can use the code below:

```
foreach (Control c1 in Controls)
{
    foreach (Control c2 in Controls)
    {
        if (!c2.Equals(c1) 
        && c1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(c2.Bounds))
        {
            // c1 has touched c2
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you iterate twice? You will already know the control you are moving so just check it's display rectangle with other top level controls (ones with parent as the form.)

Comment: Yes the above solution is where all controls can move. but if we just trace an specific element you are right!

Comment: This will still not work since for once in all iterations, you are comparing the control rectangle with itself.

Comment: @danish Thank you, however the OP could check these stuffs after tracing it ;)

Comment: Thank you Ahmad. I will check this solution when I get back home from work.

Comment: `DisplayRectangle` gives you a client rectangle w/ respect to the control itself.  As such, it will always be at (0, 0) and be the size of that control...not very useful for this scenario.  Use the `Bounds` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain display rectangle of all parent controls. For example if there is a group box maintain display rectangle of that and not of controls inside it. While moving a control, check if current display rectangle overlaps with another.