# C# Winforms - Check when moveable drawn image is over a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image drawn on the form which can be moved by the arrow keys.
It's created in the paint method as such:

```
int _x = 500; // initial x co-ordinate
int _y = 600; // initial y co-ordinate

private void testForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("carImage.png"), _x, _y, 150, 100);
}
```

I also have some labels on the form, and the aim is that when the image is moved over a label and space is pressed, the text on the label changes.

What I'm confused about is how to check if the image is at the right location when space is pressed, i.e. if it is on top of the label.

I tried a few different ways, including this:

```
case Keys.Space:
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Label)
        {
            for (int i = _x; i < _x + 150; i++)
            {
                for (int j = _y; j > _y - 100; j--)
                {
                    // If carImage within bounds of control
                    if (control.Bounds.Contains(i, j))
                        control.Text = "newText";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work in my code, and I think even if it did it may be slow, as it has to iterate through so many times.

I also tried using

```
control.Bounds.IntersectsWith(carImage.Bounds ...)
```

but I'm not sure what object type the image should be in order to use it as the method argument.

I tried making the image a type Bitmap, but it wouldn't have a .Bounds property (there is only GetBounds() ). I think I could use carImage.Height etc., but I'm still not sure how I would check whether they overlap using this.

So, two questions:

- Is there another way to check if any of the image co-ordinates overlap with the label bounds, and, if not,
- What type to set the image as so that it can be called in control.Bounds.IntersectsWith(), and how exactly to get that method to work with the image bounds (i.e. what should be inside the parentheses).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The Rectangle class has an IntersectWith function.  Determine your rectangles and use that.

Comment: Possible solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27519861/8863031

Comment: You should be able to determine that.  Where are you drawing the image?  How big is the image?  `new Rectangle(x, y, yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height)`

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it might work. However, when I draw the image (in the paint method):
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("picPlane.png"), _x, _y, 150, 100);


it isn't being assigned to a variable. Do you know how I would assign it to a variable, or use the IntersectsWith method on the image without assigning it to one?

Comment: You need to store that location; that could be done on WinForm level.

Comment: I already showed you how.  Stick a `var r = ` in front of what I provided.

Comment: The location is constantly moving though as the image is being moved around with arrow keys.

I tried putting `var image =` .... in front, but it didn't work. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious here.

Comment: You haven't shown us much code, so we can only help through these cryptic messages.  But clearly you know where the image is when you are painting, so it's hard to understand why that same information isn't available in your key event.

Comment: You're right; I'll edit my question to be more clear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Bitmap _image = new Bitmap("carImage.png");
int _x = 500; // initial x co-ordinate
int _y = 600; // initial y co-ordinate

private void testForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, _x, _y);
}

private void CheckIntersect()
{
   Rectangle imageBounds = new Rectangle(_x, _y, _image.Width, _image.Height);

   if (label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(imageBounds))
      control.Text = "newText";
}
```